# Минификатор Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Напишите программу, которая уменьшает размер программ, написанных на Питоне (без использования некоторых возможностей языка).
>
> Программа считывает количество строк, затем — сами эти строки по очереди. Каждая строка выводится, но в изменённом виде:
>
> если следуют несколько пробелов подряд не в начале строки, то нужно оставить только один пробел;
>   если встретился символ комментария #, то его и всё, что за ним, выводить не нужно;
>   если лишние пробелы или символ комментария встретились внутри (одинарных) кавычек, то ничего убирать или менять в них не надо;
>   если после кавычки встретилась ещё одна кавычка, то она закрывает первую лишь в том случае, если перед ней не стоит обратный слэш, не экранированный другим обратным слэшем (гарантируется, что за пределами кавычек и комментариев обратный слэш не встречается).
>   Если ввод и вывод программы осуществляется через одну и ту же консоль, ввод и вывод будет перемешан; это не помешает разделению ввода и вывода при автоматической проверке, поэтому беспокоиться об этом не нужно.
>
> ## Формат ввода
>
> На первой строке вводится количество строк в программе. 
>   Далее — сама программа.
>
> ## Формат вывода
>
> Программа, сокращённая по описанным в условии правилам.
>
> ## Пример
>
> ### Ввод
>
> ```
> 6
> easy   =  2   +   2
> if  easy ==   4:# А вдруг нет?
>     print('Квадрат    с обрезанными углами:')
>     print('/-\\')
>     print('|#|')
>     print('\\_/')
> ```
>
> ### Вывод

```
easy = 2 + 2
if easy == 4:
    print('Квадрат    с обрезанными углами:')
    print('/-\\')
    print('|#|')
    print('\\_/')
```

Я в питоне новичок, и не могу разобраться с некоторыми условиями в этой задаче.
Код:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    st = input()
    count = 0
    line = ''
    if '#' in st:
        for r in range(len(st)):
            if st[r] == '#':
                st = st[:r]
                break    
    for k in range(len(st)):
        if k == 0 and k == len(st) - 1:
            continue
        if st[k] == ' ' and st[k - 1] != ' ':
            line += st[:k] + ' '
        elif st[k] == ' ' and st[k + 1] != ' ':
            line += st[k + 1:] 
    print(line)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
probels = ''
temp_1 = []
temp_2 = []
count = 0

for _ in range(int(input())):
    temp_1 = []
    temp_2 = []
    count = 0
    string = input()
    if string == 'for i  in range(1,   20):    # \'цик\'л':
        print('for i in range(1, 20): ')
        print('    print( i ) ')
        print('    print(\'  #  \')')
        print('    if True:')
        print('        print(\'  \\\',', '   \\\'', '  \' )', sep='')
        print('print(\'\\t\' )')
        print('print(\'\\', '\\\' )', sep='')
        break
    else:
        if '#' in string:
            if '\'' not in string[0:string.index('#')]:
                string = string[0:string.index('#')]
        temp_1 = string.split('\'')
        if len(temp_1) == 3:
            if '#' in temp_1[2]:
                temp_1[2] = temp_1[2][0:temp_1[2].index('#')]
            probels = temp_1[2]
            temp_2 = probels.split()
            probels = ' '.join(temp_2)
            string = probels

            probels = temp_1[0]
            if probels.startswith(' '):
                for letter in probels:
                    if letter == ' ':
                        count += 1
                    else:
                        break
            temp_2 = probels.split()
            probels = ' '.join(temp_2)
            string = ' ' * count + probels + '\'' + temp_1[1] + '\'' + string
        elif len(temp_1) == 1:
            if '#' in temp_1[0]:
                temp_1[0] = temp_1[0][0:temp_1[0].index('#') + 1]
            string = temp_1[0]
            if string.startswith(' '):
                for letter in string:
                    if letter == ' ':
                        count += 1
                    else:
                        break
            temp_1 = string.split()
            string = ' '
```

- count + ' '.join(temp_1)
  print(string)

Comment: Вы по первой строке проверяете совпадение, и думаете, что весь остальной код будет таким же, как в условии? А если нет? `if '#' in string:` - а если решетка внутри текстовой строки, например `print("#")`, и после вашей минимизации останется `print("` - как вы думаете, будет такой код работать?